# true MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table (base) and a table structure is:

```
id, name, money, manager, date
```

i do to retrieve a distinct values from a table

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from base;
```

this code works but i need something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT name SUM(money) from base;
```

this code retrieve from a table only one value (name) and sum of the all money value:

like this

```
id      name      money    manager      date
===     =====     =====    =======   ===========
 1      John       3000     Scot      10.04.2013
```

i need name DISTINCT and money SUM

```
   id      name      money    manager      date
   ===     =====     =====    =======   ===========
    1      John       150     Scot      10.04.2013
    2      Mia        200     Scot      11.04.2013
    3      Monica     650     Scot      09.04.2013
   ...     ......     ...     ....      ..........
```

if i add SQL query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, SUM(money) FROM base WHERE name='Mia'
```

or

```
SELECT name, SUM(money) FROM base WHERE name='Mia'
```

code works. How to do like this on all the records in the table?

i'm using:

Mysql 5.5.24,
Delphi Xe3,
Delphi sql component Unidac

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY` will allow you to use group functions like `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN` or  `MAX`:

```
SELECT name, SUM(money) FROM base GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to get, I guess it's sume of money of all records with name Mia.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(money) FROM base WHERE name='Mia') as money, DISTINCT name FROM base WHERE name='Mia'
```

for mia

and for universal usage

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(money) FROM base b1 WHERE b1.id=b2.id) as money, DISTINCT name FROM base b2
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Klas Lindbäck said, you can use `group by` in order to calculate the sum for each name.
If you need the sum only for a given name (let's say `Mia`), you could also use this query:

```
 SELECT 'Mia' as name, SUM(money) from base where name = 'Mia';
```